# Iterate over columns in C++ matrix

Tags: c++, vector, std

I want to iterate over single row and column in `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` matrix and get their sum.

I know that I can do this in nested loop, but here is my question. Can I use

```
int val_sum = 0;
std::for_each(matrix_[row].begin(),matrix_[row].end(),[&](int x) {  val_sum += x;});
```

for columns and how to do that?

Comment: You can use nested `std::accumulate` (or nested `std::for_each`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analogous way of your proposal is to iterate the matrix rows and accumulate the elements in the given column.

```cpp
int val_sum = 0;
std::for_each(matrix.begin(),matrix.end(),[&](std::vector<int> &row) {  val_sum += row[column];});
```

But I would still prefer to use the c++11 range-loop version

```cpp
int val_sum = 0;
for ( const std::vector<int> &row : matrix )
   val_sum += row[column];
```

Comment: Your loop version is missing the inner loop.

Comment: And why you prefer the loop version ?

Comment: @ThomasSablik - You only need one loop, because you only have one variable.

Comment: @Andreimek Because the nested version is much clear to read and less prone to produce an error.

Comment: @Useless The question is how to sum up all elements of a vector of vector of int. OP mentions nested loops in the description. This doesn't look like an answer to the question. Where does `column` come from?

Comment: I think they _meant_ they wanted to sum a column in a similar way to summing a row. It wasn't entirely clear, but since they accepted this answer already I guess it met their needs

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix = { {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5} };
    const int sum = std::accumulate(matrix.cbegin(), matrix.cend(), 0, [](const auto acc, const auto row) {
        return acc + std::accumulate(row.cbegin(), row.cend(), 0);
    });
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this summing every element, rather than summing every element in a given column?

Comment: @Useless That's how I understand the question because of _"I know that I can do this in nested loop, but here is my question."_ I don't see why you would need nested loops to sum up one row or column.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest two `for_each`. You simply have to notice that every element of the outer `for_each` will be another `vector<int>`, a row. [[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/johY65T6n)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // for_each
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
    std::for_each(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), [](auto& row) {
        std::for_each(std::cbegin(row), std::cend(row), [](auto n) {
            std::cout << n << " ";
        });
        std::cout << "\n";
    });
}
```

If you want to sum all the elements of the matrix, you can use `accumulate` instead of the inner `for_each` loop. [[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/jd4n9djas)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // for_each
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <numeric>  // accumulate
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int result{};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
    std::for_each(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), [&result](auto& row) {
        result += std::accumulate(std::cbegin(row), std::cend(row), 0);
    });
    std::cout << "sum = " << result << "\n";
}
```

Or even with two nested `accumulate`. [[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/jvEjfnP4o)

```
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <numeric>  // accumulate
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
    auto result = std::accumulate(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), 0, [](auto total, auto& row) {
        return total + std::accumulate(std::cbegin(row), std::cend(row), 0);
    });
    std::cout << "sum = " << result << "\n";
}
```

If (after all, I misunderstood you from a beginning, and) you want to add all the elements of a given column. [[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/aG5fY33dq)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <numeric>  // accumulate
#include <vector>

int sum_column(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& v, size_t column)
{
    return std::accumulate(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), 0, [&column](auto total, auto& row) {
        return total + row[column];
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
    std::cout << "sum of column 1 = " << sum_column(v, 1) << "\n";
}
```